# A simple Decryption Program using Python

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm

This is a program that can decrypt the codes that have been encrypted using the algorithm that [my previously posted encryption program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239442/a-simple-encryption-program-using-python) follows, you just need to enter the encrypted text from that program.

I got a lot of suggestions from people on the encryption post, I have tried to make this program as short as possible (in my efforts), I did not use the method they suggested to shorten functions because I don't want to use it without understanding how it works, I will implement it in my further programs as soon as I understand it...

Thank You for the suggestions on the previous program, it helped me reduce the length of this program by 16 lines.

Please let me know what you think about this program

Python Code :

```
alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def position_in_alphabets(tofind):
    for i in range(0,26):
        if tofind == alphabets[i]:
            position = i+1
            break
    return position

def decrypt(a):
    output = ''
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        character = a[i]
        z = i+1
        y = position_in_alphabets(character)
        x = z+y-26
        if x>len(alphabets):
            x = x % len(alphabets)
        alpha = alphabets[x-1]
        output += alpha
    return output

print ()
print ("NOTE : Please enter just lowercase characters (no special characters) and no spaces")
print ()
given = input("Please enter the word to be decrypted : ")
output = decrypt(given)
print ()
print ("The word which is coded as ",given," is : ",output)
```

Thank You :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use built in methods!

Your `position_in_alphabets` function can be reduced to one line. In fact, replace `y = ...` with the following:

```
alphabets.index(character) + 1
```

[`index`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/index) returns the first occurrence of the character in question. Since you're working with the alphabet, it will return the position of the character in that string. Then you just need to add one.

## Never trust user input

Instead of trusting the user will only enter lowercase characters after telling them to do so, call `.lower()` on the `input` to change the string to all lowercase letters.

---

*I'm going to step through each line of the main function now.*

---

## f"" strings

I would use [`f""`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) strings so you can directly format your variables in your strings. In this case, it reduces the clutter that `print("...", var, "...", var, "...")` causes. It would instead be `print(f"... {var} ... {var} ...")`.

## Naming conventions ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions))

`a` isn't really a good parameter name. A variable/parameter name should represent what that variable is holding or is doing. I would use `string`, since you're working with them in this program.

```
def decrypt(string):
```

## Use enumerate

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) allows you to work through an iterable with the index and the value at that position in the iterable. It gets rid of having to `iterable[i]` and all that junk.

```
output = ''
spaces = 0
for index, character in enumerate(string):
```

## Allowing spaces

Spaces are really easy to deal with. If the character is a space, simply add `" "` to the output and [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue), quite literally, to the next iteration.

```
if character == " ":
    output += " "
    spaces += 1
    continue
```

## Compress your computations

Instead of having a bunch of one character variable names `x`, `y`, `z`, I would do all the computations in one step and assign them to a variable. I've done so, and used `position`, because that's what you're calculating.

```
position = (index + 1) + (alphabet.index(character) + 1) - 26
```

## Simplify your reassignments

Have a look at this:

```
if position > len(alphabet):
    position %= len(alphabet)
```

It's the same thing as `position = position % len(alphabet)`, but shorter (also called in place modulus). It also works for the other operators (`+-*/`).

## Don't make variables you don't need

The sole purpose of `alpha` is to hold the value at the passed position in `alphabet`, then you add alpha to `output`. How about you just skip the first step and add it right to `output`?

```
output += alphabet[position - 1]
```

---

All in all, your final program looks like this:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def decrypt(string: str) -> str:
    output = ''
    spaces = 0
    for index, character in enumerate(string):
        if character == " ":
            output += " "
            spaces += 1
            continue
        position = (index + 1) + (alphabet.index(character) + 1) - len(alphabet)
        if position > len(alphabet):
            position %= len(alphabet)
        output += alphabet[position - 1 - spaces]
    return output

word = input("Please enter the word to be decrypted: ").lower()
output = decrypt(word)
print(f"The word '{word}' decrypted is '{output}'")
```

We use `spaces` to shift the index back for every space we've encountered.

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful, but there's one problem, the addition of the space feature interferes with the output, like the output for 'zzzz' is 'abcd', and if the user enters 'zz zz', then shouldn't the output be 'ab cd' instead of 'ab de' as it does in the version that you gave? I want a method in which the value of i does not increase by one when the character is [spcae], so we can count the number of spaces found and then reduce the value of i by the number of spaces...that should work, right?

Comment: And that would require a counter, too, so what should I do?

Comment: I figured it out, we can create a variable number_of_spaces, let's say and every time the character is a space, we can increase the variable by one, and then change the second-last statement of decrypt() to : output+=alphabets[position-1-number_of_spaces], it works, now the output for "zz zz" is "ab cd", Thanks for the review

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu I missed that, thanks for catching it. The code has been updated.

Comment: I would have add type annotations @Linny . Great answer tho!